# How does multi-line logging work in Lambda -> CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My multi-line logging events all end up multi-events - one event per line. According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html):

> Each call to LambdaLogger.log() results in a CloudWatch Logs event...

but then:

> However, note that AWS Lambda treats each line returned by System.out
>   and System.err as a separate event.

Looking inside [LambdaAppender's source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-log4j2/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/log4j2/LambdaAppender.java), it seems that it proceeds to log the event to `System.out` anyway. So does that mean multi-line messages will always be broken down into multiple event?

I have read about configuring the [multi_line_start_pattern](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html), but that seems only applicable when you get to deploy a log agent, which isn't accessible in Lambda.

[Edit] `LambdaAppender` logs to [`LambdaLogger`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/LambdaRuntime.java) which logs to `System.out`.

[Edit] I found some post where a workaround was suggested - use '\r' for the eol when printing the messages. This seems to work for messages that my code produces. Stack traces logged everywhere are still a problem.

[Edit] **I have been using two workarounds**:

1. Log complex data structures (e.g. sizable maps) in JSON. CloudWatch actually recognizes JSON strings in log events, and pretty print them.
2. Replace '\n' with '\r'. For stack traces I created a utility method (this is in Kotlin, but the idea is generic enough):

   ```
   fun formatThrowable(t: Throwable): String {
       val buffer = StringWriter()
       t.printStackTrace(PrintWriter(buffer))
       return buffer.toString().replace("\n", "\r")
   }
   ```

I think in the long run a more ideal solution would be an `Appender` implementation that decorates `ConsoleAppender`, which would do the `\r` replacement on all messages passing through.

Comment: Where do you see it writing to `System.out`? Because I see it writing to a `LambdaLogger` instance, which is part of the non-distributed AWS runtime code.

Comment: If I read it correctly, `LambdaLogger` source is in the same project actually: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/LambdaRuntime.java.

Comment: You certainly seem to be correct -- I didn't take the time to look at the other projects in the repo before commenting. However, I know (or at least believe) that I saw an exception logged in the same CloudWatch event as the main message. Which makes me wonder if maybe `System.out` is an AWS-specific  `PrintStream` that flushes based on writes rather than newline. That's complete speculation on my part, but would be fairly easy to verify with (1) `Class.getName()` and (2) printing a string with embedded newlines.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to use json in your logs. Instead of sending multiline outputs, send a formatted json (regardless of the language you are using, you will find a lib that already does that for you)

You will be amazed how easy it gets to browse your logs from there. For instance, `aws cloudwatch insights` automatically detects your fields, it allow to parse them and query them within seconds

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the project [slf4j-simple-lambda](https://github.com/microlam-io/slf4j-simple-lambda) and to refer to this [blog](https://frank-afriat.medium.com/solving-the-java-aws-lambda-logging-problem-305b06df457f) for more explanations.

Using slf4j and slf4j-simple-lambda is solving elegantly your problem and the solution stay lightweight. The project includes the usage of the parameter `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.newlineMethod` which is there to solve this problem. By default, its value is auto and should be able to detect automatically the need for manual newline handling.

Discloser: I am co-author of slf4j-simple-lambda and author of the blog.